# Why is "struggled to process" more common than "struggled processing"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrase-choice, colloquial-language

In many cases, you'd write verb + gerund:

> His eyes stopped **to sting/stinging** after a while.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20stopped%20stinging%2C%20stopped%20to%20sting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstopped%20stinging%3B%2Cc0)

What is it an exception with the verbs *struggle* and *process*?

> He struggled **to process/processing** the news.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=struggled%20processing%2C%20struggled%20to%20process&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstruggled%20to%20process%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop is a [transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stop), whereas to struggle is an [intransitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/struggle).

From [this source](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/verbs):

> A transitive verb is a verb that requires an object to receive the action.

whereas

> An intransitive verb does not take an object. Using an object
> immediately after an intransitive verb will create an incorrect
> sentence.  However, there may be other information after the verb,
> such as one or more prepositional phrases or an adverb.

So in your first example, the gerund `stinging` is the noun receiving the  stop action. Whereas in the second example, struggle *cannot* (grammatically, at least) take an object, so you achieve that goal with the infinitive instead.